# Deliver: Defense Officer

Tags: x-rebirth

So I got up to a part in the plot where Deliver: Defense Officer is the objective. Initially it looks as though my freighter is the destination but when I land my Defense Officer is not on the ship (but is in space) and there seams to be nothing else to do.

What am I supposed to do??

Comment: Mission tracking in this game is such a HUGE step back from X3... its not funny...

Comment: I don't mean to be nitpicky, but how did you get your captain on the freither? It's the same menu selection :)

Comment: they just didn't spell it out to me again lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to contact him over the menu, because when you re-docked he doesn't show up... so when you're docked you should be able to just press <kbd>enter</kbd> to go to crew, contact the officer, and say "work here".

Comment: Why is this down-voted? This is exactly what I realized I had to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to command your officer "Work here", and then get yourself on Albion Skunk. This should trigger next step of mission.

Comment: The officer is NOT VISIBLE on my ship when I am landed. In space I can talk to him. I did assign a captain to my freighter already so I know the gist.

Comment: Does it matter that he is a Teladi? I noticed a lot of humans don't like them...

Comment: I am not sure, is it listed in albion skunk crew list? you don't need to interact with him directly in this mission.

Comment: How do I check that? I know I can talk to him and I did hire him (for a premium too considering how many credits we have at the start). So far I have just bought a human officer (in addition) and heading to my ship now.

Comment: Now neither appears (reloading save)

Comment: Ok so I think he was automatically assigned to my crew and therefore I can't reassign him before unassigning him.... does that sound right?

Comment: Got it! Had to go to him in space and say Your Fired! and then land on my ship.. takes a twisted mind to come up with something like that....

Comment: add this as an answer, looks like as glitch in mission.

Comment: No wait, he just did an animation/cut scene of leaving the ship and then vanished.... POOF!

Comment: after he got down from ship mission objective changed? try find other officer.

Comment: No the objective is the same. I suspect that was him 'leaving' me cause I fired him. Still back to square one.